# Storing persistent variable in either nginx or php

Tags: php, nginx, persistent-storage

I have an API key that needs to be called from a particular file and as I do not want to store the API key in a source code, I've decided to encrypt the API key using PBKDF2 and decrypting the file once with my password to retrieve my API key whenever I start or restart my server.

However, I could not find a way to store the API key as a persistent variable where I only have to activate the PHP file that retrieves the API key once. Having tried include, require_once and global in php. I also could not use any files or database to store the API key retrieved as this would make what I did pointless.

Is there any way to store the API key as a variable where I am able to call it with let's say my API.php whenever the users need to use the API on my website without using any databases and files?

I am also using nginx as my server.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you could use environmental variables using getenv on php to retrieve the value. I know it works fine with Apache, you have to check on nginx how to set them up

Comment: Storing this key within the nginx config isn't an option for you too?

Comment: I was replying but there are many better resources about this. See this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/199248/why-use-env-whats-wrong-with-storing-secrets-in-a-config-php-file-outside-roo

Comment: I managed to use environment variables to store. But it seems once my session ends as in my ssh into the server, the variable gets cleared too. I found that you could actually store it inside ~/.bash_profile , but doing this still stores the variable information. Is there an alternate method? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Well, you need to store that key somewhere anyway, right? If you don't want to store it on your nginx server no matter would it be stored in PHP code, database, nginx config etc, the only way I see is to store it on some other server you trust and get that key via remote HTTP call allowing access only for your first server IP.